# How to Check Permissions on List API Without Any Filters

Tags: permissions, api-design

I'm working on a List API that is supposed to return all objects the calling user has access to without needing any filters that would simplify the permissions checking. The permissions model is a bit complex, I will try to explain it with a similar example:

Consider a web shop with an API that lists products available from the catalog. Each product belongs to a certain category of products. Users of the web shop are only allowed to view products that belong to specific categories where the user has access to the category

How could one implement the permissions checking for a generic list API (e.g. `/api/v1/products`) and still only return products that belong to categories the user has access to? Consider that there can be an arbitrarily large number of categories and users may have permissions for any possible subset of all categories.

The easy solution for building the permissions for the List API would be to only allow listing products for one category at a time. The API would probably be something like `GET /api/v1/categories/{category_id}/products`. This way it would be trivial to check whether the user is allowed to list products for a given category and we could query the database for products that match the passed category. This doesn't work because there is a business requirement that excludes this approach.

Another possible approach would be to start pulling all products from the database and to filter them afterwards, something like this:

```
productsToReturn = []
while productsToReturn.length < pageSize
  products = getNextPageOfProductsFromDb()
  productsToReturn.push(...products.filter((product) => userHasAccessToCategory(product.category));

return productsToReturn
```

The challenge I see with this approach is that it's quite hard to return uniform pages of products back to the user. If we attempt to fill an entire page then we might end up pulling every product from the DB which could be catastrophic in terms of performance. If we want to return how many pages the user can expect in total we would also have to go over every product.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I work for the company building this solution)

You can implement a fine-grained authorization solution. https://openfga.dev/ (open source) or https://docs.fga.dev/ (managed).

1. Define your business model:

```
type product
    define viewer: viewer from category
    define category: [category]

type category
   define viewer: [user]

type user
```

2. Assign categories to each product: `Write(category:cars, category, product:bumper)`
3. Assign users to each category: `Write(user:anne, viewer, category:cars)`
4. Issue this call: `ListObjects(user:anne, relation=viewer, type=product)`. It should give you an array with `[product:bumper]`

Can try it out here: https://play.fga.dev/stores/create/?id=01H7ZT8A7NF9WH5RMQ3FWEZ14A